# MS Access: What object model does the container object Forms belong to?

Tags: object, ms-access, dao

It is my understanding that the DAO and ADO object models only have objects for data access, such as tables and queries, and do not have objects that relate to the presentation of data, such as forms and reports.

In agreement with that, the long list of objects in the [MS documentation of DAO objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/microsoft-data-access-objects-reference) does not include forms or reports.

Also in agreement, the [MS documentation on the DAO container object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/container-object-dao) says "The following table lists the name of each Container object defined by the Microsoft Access database engine" and the said table lists three objects: Databases, Tables, and Relations.

However, when I run the following routine in Access 2007 VBA:

```
Sub ListDocuments()

Dim oDB As DAO.Database: Set oDB = CurrentDb()
Dim oContainer As DAO.Container

For Each oContainer In oDB.Containers
    Debug.Print oContainer.Name
  Next oContainer

End Sub
```

I get the following output:

```
DataAccessPages
Databases
Forms
Modules
Relationships
Reports
Scripts
SysRel
Tables
```

There are two problem with this output:

- Minor problem: It has a container object called "Relationships" and not "Relations". Does this indicate a typo in the documented list of container objects quoted above?
- Worse problem. The list of DAO container objects includes one called "Forms". Note that this is NOT the same as the object of the same name in the Access object model. The [MS documentation on the Access object Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.forms) says that it includes only open forms. That page says that the Access object that includes closed forms is AllForms. In an Access file with one form which is currently closed, in the Immediate Window, `? Forms.Count` = 0, but `? CurrentDb().Containers("Forms").Documents.Count` = 1 . So these two things, both called "Forms", are different things.

This container object Forms does not seem to be documented anywhere. And its existence seems to contradict the statement quoted above that Access only defines three container objects. And further, since it is in the DAO object Containers, it seems to also contradict the idea that DAO does not include objects for forms and reports.

So my question is, where does this container object Forms come from? What object model does it belong to? If you know the answer, it would be helpful if you could link to some documentation for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers and online documentation all contain good information worth understanding if you really want to grasp the details for programming Access.  However, they often exclude critical details that are either assumed or forgotten.  Before directly answering your questions myself, consider these points:

- Technically, an "object" model is a bad choice of words since the more proper term is a class model.  Generally, an object is an in-memory instance of class.  During run time, there is indeed a hierarchy of actual objects, but sometimes it useful to refer not to a particular instance (i.e. object), but rather the overall class.  I usually try to be very careful about the terminology, but especially in reference to some of these older models, the names and terms used in documentation are (frankly) sloppy.  This is a disclaimer for all of the failed terminology.  I'll do my best to clarify where a distinction is critical to understanding.
- There is redundancy in the various object models related to Access.  There may be good reasons for some of this redundancy, but at least some of the redundancy may have **no** good reason (at least none that are published).  Rather some parts of the various components are a result of a mature product that has evolved over time. Different information needs to be exposed at different levels, but rather than just making the entire model open and accessible and consistent, it was designed with an "as needed" paradigm.

  - The redundancy exists both

    - *in name*: Different classes with the same or similar names are not identical, but may provide a different set of methods and properties for manipulating the same underlying entity.  This is likewise true for names of collections and enumerations.  Sometimes they don't even manipulate the same underlying entity, although they may provide similar functionality (like ADO.Recordset and DAO.Recordset)
    - *in availability*: Some identical objects are exposed via different collections and properties of different parent/container objects.

---

> It has a container object called "Relationships" and not "Relations". Does this indicate a typo in the documented list of container objects quoted above?

Yes, any discrepancy between "Relationships" and "Relations" is just a mistake and likely has no deeper meaning.

> Where does this container object Forms come from?

*This is only a guess, but at least an attempt at a direct answer:*

The container object is provided as a backward reference for discovery of related objects.  When MS Access creates/loads the database via DAO, it apparently adds additional Container objects for its own purposes.  DAO provides a generic Containers collection and allows other objects to add to it.

Even though DAO's purpose is to simply access and represent to the data itself, apparently MS determined it was useful to provide a way to publish (a.k.a. expose) related objects via the DAO object model.  I would consider it like the `Parent` property of many objects.  Without such a `Parent` property, there is often no built-in way to determine the relationship of an object to its source.  Likewise, in a complex application, there may have been no other way to determine various details of the database without the containers collection.  Albert D. Kallal already emphasized there need not be any particular connection between DAO and the Container objects.  Perhaps it is true that the Container classes and objects really have no meaningful relationship, but MS obviously decided for some reason to tack that onto the DAO object model, so I find Mr. Kallal's explanation lacking.  Access is still a proprietary product with hidden methods and MS does not publish all API's and class details.  I honestly don't believe it was that arbitrary--MS had their reasons even if they don't share it.

> What object model does it belong to?

From what is described in documentation AND from exploring details in the *VBA Object Browser* and using some VBA methods like `TypeName`, etc., it appears that the `Containers` collection and `Container` objects are indeed part of the DAO object model.  However, the Container objects (and related Document objects) themselves can refer to and/or hold objects outside of the DAO object model.  Strictly speaking, the concept of an Access Form is outside of DAO.  The actual classes and object for Forms are part of the Access object model.

---

To go a little further, the various collections are not just simply "open forms" vs. "all forms".  Although they all return conceptual entities called "forms", they do not even return the same type of run-time objects.  The `CurrentDB.Database.Containers(FormContainerIndex)` collection returns `Container` objects with `Document` objects (where FormContainerIndex may or may not equal 2).  The `Application.CurrentProject.AllForms` collection returns instances of `AccessObject`.  The `Application.Forms` collection returns actual form objects that are of specific form-class types.

I think this is a great question.  The documentation links in the question reveal how confusing this can get, since various concepts are all blended together *in context of Access*.  One tree of the MS documentation makes clear that DAO and ADO are distinct and separate from Access, but then another documentation branch puts the same objects together in a list of related data-access concepts.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. While bringing some measure of clarity to the issue, you've also shown where the issue is just intrinsically murky.

Comment: If I may make one correction, the use of `acForm` for the container Forms works by coincidence. `? acForm` = 2 and Forms happens to be Container #2 in the Containers collection: `? CurrentDB.Containers(acForm).Name` = Forms. But this doesn't work for these enumeration constants in general. For example, `? CurrentDB.Containers(acTable).Name` = DataAccessPages and `? CurrentDB.Containers(acQuery).Name` = Databases. (And besides, there is no Queries container because they're included in the Tables container.)

Comment: Would you please let me know if you agree with my correction or if I've misunderstood something in what you wrote?

Comment: I did not verify that particular constant (`acForm`) since what I wrote was on a very high level, so it was just borrowed from one of the other examples.  I think you are correct, since the Containers collection has no predefined set of Container objects in it (excepting those which DAO automatically adds), so it would make no sense to have enumeration constants which define the index for those.  Yes, it would be a mere coincident if acForm does actually index into the Forms Containers.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from:

```
Microsoft Access
```

You can easily check this:

```
? Forms.Parent.Name
Microsoft Access
```

This contains all forms, open or not:

```
Application.CurrentProject.AllForms
```

The current database refers to that container. These will return the same count:

```
? CurrentDb.Containers(acForm).Documents.Count
? Application.CurrentProject.AllForms.Count
```

*CurrentDb* (or any other *DAO.Database* object) is probably where DAO comes in - in the documentation you refer to.

Comment: That Forms is not the same as the container object Forms. Here's proof. The current Access file I have open has one form, which is closed. `? Forms.Count` = 0, but `? CurrentDb().Containers("Forms").Documents.Count` = 1 .

Comment: Nothing to proof. The one collection holds all forms, the other open forms only. That's by design.

Comment: Yes, but you answered my question of where the container object Forms comes from by showing that the parent of the Access object Forms is Access. But the Forms you showed the parent of is not the same thing as the container object Forms I am asking about.

Comment: But the content is the same list. See edited answer, please.

Comment: The content of container object Forms is the same as the content of Access object AllForms, and is different from Access object Forms.

Comment: Only if not _all_ forms are open. Also, `Microsoft Access` holds the actual Form _objects_, not only their names.

Answer (score 0):

Not really much of anything to write about here.

Access has some “container” objects. We could store pictures, PDF documents, or whatever in those containers.

And we could even store say the Relationship diagram in those containers. (Oh, wait – they did that!!!).

The containers are just that – some containers in the Access application.

As such, they can quite much arbitrarily be anything the desires of the Access application designers wanted to store in the containers.

I mean, really, this is not much different then a table. That table might have invoices, or say have some customers

To THEN infer that DAO has a “customers” object or an “invoice” object as part of the DAO object model would make little sense here.

The containers “objects” are just that – a container of things. They have little relevance to the DAO object model.

The “containers” is a list of objects provided by the Access system, not DAO.

There is no “containers” method or “containers” property of the DAO object model.

Now to be fair, the “native” database engine used in Access is JET (now called ACE). And to be fair, since the access database engine is tied VERY close to the DAO object model, then it is most certainly fair to state that Access (the developer tool) is tied far closer to DAO then it is to ADO.

While you are most free to use DAO or ADO for grabbing data from the JET/ACE engine, DAO is certainly the preferred choice here.

The “main” reason for this preference, is that DAO is VERY tight tied to the JET/ACE database engine. Access originally was built around the JET + dao library code, so its roots are tighter with the DAO object model.

However, if you going to grab data from SQL server, then for a long time, most developers preferred the ADO object model. There are several advantages to using ADO when say using SQL server, or say MySQL, or Oracle as the back end database with MS-access as the front end.

The “major” advantage of using ADO, is the SQL used for ADO is “closer” to the SQL syntax that the “industry” standard uses (ansi-92). As a result, your SQL you write with ADO will work (in general) without changes if you use SQL server, or say Oracle as the back end. (And you can likely switch between the two databases without having to change the sql syntax you use).

With DAO, you are using Access (jet) SQL syntax, or better said, JET/ACE syntax. When you using ADO, but STILL use the JET/ACE engine, you get to use the sql ansi-92 syntax. The result is your syntax for the sql will MUCH more match the syntax used on SQL server, or say oracle.

For an access + JET/ACE application, the recommended standard choice is to use DAO. (18 years ago, Microsoft changed the “default” object model to ADO in Access 2000. Developers staged somewhat of a “revolt”, and in Access 2003, they returned DAO as the default. (You can to this day, STILL choose either object model, or worse “intermix” the two – don’t go there!!!). So Microsoft did not force a change, but the “default” setting was ADO – but we just always changed the reference back to DAO and kept on writing code as we always did.

So for a good number of years, Microsoft was pushing everyone to use ADO – including the very popular MS-access system.

However, most of us developers ignored this advice from Microsoft, and continue to use DAO when building native access applications. And as noted, for a rather long time now, DAO is the default object model. Because DAO been somewhat “deprecated”, the Access team took the DAO object and code library and they now own this library. (Before it was simply a standard Microsoft library that all developers could use). So for V6, vb.net etc., they tended to use ADO.

So you can now “read” that DAO is deprecated, but Access uses an updated and newer version that is included with the ACE database engine. (So while DAO as a standalone object library is depreciated, the DAO code updates, and new features continue in Access as the ACE data engine object.

When you set a reference to the ACE data engine then all of your DAO code should work just fine.
What this means (since access 2007), you do NOT need to set an external reference to the DAO object model – it is now part of the JET/ACE database engine. (Prior to access 2007, you had to set a reference to DAO. And if you were going to use ADO, you ALWAYS had to set that reference, and you still do to this day)

This change was made since really only the Access community and developers were using DAO – most other platforms were using ADO (for many reasons, but one big reason was ADO was NOT tied nor did it have roots of origin in the MS-access database engine like DAO does, and still does to this day.

Remember, for about 5-10 years, Microsoft did not have SQL server, so Access + DAO was their “big deal”. When they finally started selling SQL server, then of course things changed in regards to Microsoft pushing DAO. DAO was “primary” a MS-access data engine technology.

If you do in the future move the data from Access to say sql server, and continue to use MS-access as the GUI front end, the access community STILL suggests you stick with whatever object model you used to develop your application with. So access applications developed with DAO, but using sql server as the back end database work just fine, and should remain as such.

And if you developed with ADO, then you want to continue if you start using SQL server with Access. Note that I am talking about VBA code you write – specific ADO recordsets.

You still always use the “same” internal containers that exist in Access – these containers do NOT change if you use ADO or DAO when writing code to modify data in the access client.

ADO certainly has some advantages if you going to use say SQL server as the back end from “day 1” with Access as front end, but even in those cases, if your access application was written using DAO, then I would continue to use DAO – even with SQL server.

However, for .net developers, Visual Basic developers, they likely honed their skills using the ADO object model, and when they use MS-access as the development tool, then they can continue to use their “long time” familiar with the ADO data object model when writing code in MS-access.

As noted, I don’t recommend mixing the two object models in a given single application, as that just gets confusing.

edit:

To quote from this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/container-object-dao

***Each Database object has a Containers collection consisting of built-in Container objects. Applications can define their own document types and corresponding containers (Microsoft Access database engine databases only); however, these objects may not always be supported through DAO.***

***Some of these Container objects are defined by the Microsoft Access database engine while others may be defined by other applications. The following table lists the name of each Container object defined by the Microsoft Access database engine and what type of information it contains***.

Comment: And to answer your question? the containers object is a Access application object .

Comment: You say "The “containers” is a list of objects provided by the Access system, not DAO." MS disagrees with you. See "Containers collection (DAO)" at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/containers-collection-dao . And there is no Containers object listed in "Object model (Access)" at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/access/object-model .

Comment: You missed my point. Because I decide to add some tables such as invoice and customers to a system, I would not then state that “invoice” is part of the DAO object model as a result. Access certainly uses DAO to “hold” that container, but that does not by ANY logic THEN suggest that “invoices” or that “container” object is now part of the DAO object model. Access has built in containers. Your referencing a Access reference, not a DAO only reference. Fire up Visual Studio or some other developer tool – you not see the containers object. Since it you using Access, then really no worry here.

Comment: See my "edit" I added to my answer. It simply states that some of these collecitons are added by the application (in this case Access). They may not necessary exist if you JUST using the DAO object model.  So Access certainly exposes a hodge podge of features and they used DAO to acheive this. So access certainly adds a good number of features compared to "just" DAO objects on their own.

Comment: the IMPORTANT part I quote:"Some of these Container objects are defined by the Microsoft Access database engine while others may be defined by other applications."

Comment: So what is your answer to my question? What object model does the container object Forms belong to? Or are you saying the question is invalid and there is no object model that it belongs to?

Comment: It depends on semantics. If you answer "yes" to a invoice table being part of the DAO object model with a database that has a table called "invoice", then I have to answer yes to your question (it is part of DAO). If you answer no, you don't consider "invoices" as part of the DAO object model, then the answer is no. As I pointed out, the Access application object on startup will create some of these container objects and you use DAO to get at these objects. However, if you not using Access and just DAO, then those containers will not exist. The containers are created by Access - not DAO.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal  Once again you share many interesting details, but go beyond the context of the question. The first part of your answer makes it seem silly to relate DAO to containers and you even say *"They have little relevance to the DAO object model."*  Yet CONTAINERS **ARE** PART OF THE DAO object model! Not only in documentation, but also in reality... containers are filled with Access objects!  It is not often that an object model has such a generic container for unrelated objects.  Your answer really did not explain why Access would choose to expose its object in the DAO container.

Comment: Not my intention to make it seem “silly”, but as I note, if you consider objects stored in the DAO system part of DAO, then how you answer the question will change. Some don’t consider the “existence” of objects that you use DAO to grab and get as part of DAO, but only DAO being used as the repository. However some take the view that is does mean yes, it is part of DAO. As to why Access extends and stores stuff in DAO? Well, that was likely just a convenient choice the developers of Access made – I mean, where else should they have stored such things? So no surprise here.

Comment: I should also add to my knowledge, that these containers are not accessible if you using the DAO object library, you have to use the Access application object.

Answer (score 0):

No sure how untimely this is, but I came across it, didn't read the whole thing, so i hope this wasn't already answered above. From a cursory read, though, it seems someone missed something somewhere.

Here is a little code I'm using to try to understand the quirks of VBA, along with its results. Results first, code after.

Call DumpDBContainers()

Current database contains 9 containers

Container DataAccessPages               contains 0 documents
Container Databases                     contains 3 documents
Container Forms                         contains 14 documents
Container Modules                       contains 20 documents
Container Relationships                 contains 4 documents
Container Reports                       contains 0 documents
Container Scripts                       contains 22 documents
Container SysRel                        contains 1 documents
Container Tables                        contains 151 documents

```
Public Sub DumpDBContainers()

Dim dbs As Database, Cntr As Container
Dim bNmeOnly As Boolean

Set dbs = CurrentDb()

Debug.Print " "
Debug.Print "Current database contains " & dbs.Containers.count & " containers"
Debug.Print " "

For Each Cntr In dbs.Containers
    Debug.Print "Container " & Cntr.Name & Space(30 - Len(Cntr.Name)) & "contains " & Cntr.Documents.count & " documents"
Next Cntr

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

on a new database you get fewer containers:
Current database contains 3 containers

```
Container Databases           contains 1 documents
   MSysDb
Container Relationships       contains 0 documents
Container Tables              contains 5 documents
   MSysACEs
   MSysComplexColumns
   MSysObjects
   MSysQueries
   MSysRelationships
```